# Why does sort ignore the total ordering methods defined in my class?

Tags: python, sorting, python-dataclasses

Given the following class:

```
@functools.total_ordering
class Entry:
    def __init__(self, nr: list[int, int] = None, p: int = 0) -> None:
        self.nr = nr if nr is not None else [0, 0]
        self.p = p

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Entry(nr={self.nr}, p={self.p})"

    def __eq__(self, other: Entry) -> bool:
        return (self.nr[0] == other.nr[0] and self.nr[1] >= other.nr[1]) or (self.nr[0] > other.nr[0])

    def __gt__(self, other: Entry) -> bool:
        return (self.nr[0] == other.nr[0] and self.nr[1] < other.nr[1]) or (self.nr[0] < other.nr[0])
```

And a list of entries:

```
L = [
    Entry(nr=[98, 111], p=0),
    Entry(nr=[111, 98], p=1), 
    Entry(nr=[98, 111], p=2), 
    Entry(nr=[111, 99], p=3), 
    Entry(nr=[99, 101], p=4), 
    Entry(nr=[101, 108], p=5), 
    Entry(nr=[108, -1], p=6)
]
```

Calling `L.sort()` is expected to produce the following ordering (only `p` values shown for brevity): `[0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 1, 3]`.

**But nothing happens! Why not?**

I have also experimented with making the class a `dataclass` by replacing the `__init__` with the following (and adding a `dataclass` annotation to the class, of course), but that didn't change anything. I'd prefer it to be a `dataclass`, so, that I don't have to provide an implementation of `__repr__`.

```
nr: list[int, int] = dataclasses.field(default_factory=lambda: [0, 0])
p: int = 0
```

Comment: Are you sure you implemented the right magic methods?  Your `__eq__` doesn't look very much like an equality comparison to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell it's just a logic error in your comparator methods -- note that `__eq__` is for `==`, and `__gt__` is for `>`.

Your `__eq__` is implemented more like a `<=` operator, which means it's not testing for equality in any conventional sense, and is in fact non-commutative, which you should expect to produce some weird behavior (including stuff like `sort` not doing anything because it thinks all the items are equivalent).

If you just do:

```
    def __eq__(self, other: 'Entry') -> bool:
        return (self.nr == other.nr)

    def __gt__(self, other: 'Entry') -> bool:
        return (self.nr > other.nr)
```

then `__eq__` has more useful behavior, `functools.total_ordering` is able to fill in the rest of the methods, and you get exactly the sorting behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Weird, it was working when I had `Entry` extend `NamedTuple` and `Entry.nr` was a `tuple`, and there was no change in the `__eq__` implementation. Anyway, the implementation you've shown does the job, and I can make `Entry` a `dataclass`, so, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: `NamedTuples` provide their own comparators IIRC, so the ones you wrote might not have been getting used (or at least weren't being used by `functools.total_ordering`).  You probably had the same bug but its scope of impact was sufficiently limited that this particular test didn't reveal it.  :)

Comment: Looks like I can get rid of the custom ordering methods by doing this:
@dataclasses.dataclass(order=True)
class Entry:
    nr: list[int, int] = dataclasses.field(default_factory=lambda: [0, 0])
    p: int = dataclasses.field(default_factory=int, compare=False)